# OpenWRT hairpin L2 traffic

Tags: networking, openwrt, macvlan

I have an OpenWRT Router with embedded switch.

I have a KVM machine with macvtap network access.

I need guest to host communication.

By connecting the host to my Cisco switch hairpin traffic is allowed.
How do I achieve this behavior on the OpenWRT device's switch?

Comment: on a linux *bridge* that's [hairpin_mode](https://virt.kernelnewbies.org/MacVTap) (look in VEPA). Now if the switch_dev associated to the bridge supports this feature (or it's implemented on the software side), maybe setting this on the bridge would activate it on the switch. I couldn't find reference for this in [switch_dev's doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/switchdev.txt) but you can still try it (either writing to /sys or using bridge link set ... hairpin on)

Comment: also it's not very clear what feature is in use, considering the standard openwrt tool is swconfig. its doc refers to [The rise of Linux-based networking hardware](https://lwn.net/Articles/720313/), and tells that swconfig isn't using "DSA" (then considered inferior, but now probably the reverse: better). So my previous comment won't work with swconfig. I still provided some useful links in comments.

Comment: @A.B the brctl executable doesn't have hairpin as a command on the OpenWRT build I use.

Comment: I was talking about the bridge command, not brctl (new features might be available only with ip link and bridge, rather than ifconfig and brctl). Anyway, I doubt this can work as explained before